# pip lists wrong installed version of package?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-2.6, pycrypto

On Ubuntu 10.04, my problem is that `pip freeze` and `sudo pip freeze` both report the wrong version of a package installed. I can do `sudo pip install -I pycrypto --upgrade` and it will go through and install the package (version 2.6.1), but then `pip freeze` lists the installed version as 2.0.1. I also cannot uninstall the package, so it seems like something is going wrong. How can I fix this?

**Output:**

```
$ sudo pip uninstall pycrypto
Can't uninstall 'pycrypto'. No files were found to uninstall.
$ pip uninstall pycrypto
Can't uninstall 'pycrypto'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

For reference and common issues, I have pip installed, and can do:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (python 2.6)
```

And I see the correct pip version, seems like everything is good there. `sudo pip --version` also yields the same output. I can diff the outputs from `pip freeze` and `sudo pip freeze` and there are no differences there. `which pip` and `sudo which pip` yield the same thing.

**More Info:**

If I do `pip install -I pycrypto --upgrade` without `sudo` I get an error that maybe someone could clarify? When I install with `sudo` I get no errors. I feel like this is related, but not my issue.

`InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_ndempkow/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KkVjn4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ndempkow/pycrypto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for anyone who has a similar issue, I think the problem is that I somehow had the `python-crypto` package installed from aptitude, as well as `pycrypto` installed with pip. To check this I did `dpkg --get-selections` and saw that `python-crypto` was installed, so I removed that with `sudo apt-get remove python-crypto` and then I was able to do `sudo pip uninstall pycypto`. That finally got it to disappear from `pip freeze` so I could then install the correct version.